# Как вывести конкретный елемент масива в начало?

Tags: php

Есть масив, нужно перенести значение "производитель" на первое место, тоесть должно стоять перед "Используемый кофе: молотый / зерновой", количество елементов в масиве может быть разное

[image: Масив]

```
           <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-specification">
              <div class="tab-bg">
                 <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></strong></td>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
                       <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php } ?>
                 </table>
              </div>
           </div>
           <?php } ?>
```

Comment: "Производитель"  всегда в конце? ..... Данные откуда, из БД?

Comment: <?php echo $attribute[6]['text']; ?>

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот именно, что не всегда в конце, да даные из БД, это характеристики с OpenCart-a, если быть детальнее

Comment: @Даниил  как вариант конечно, но количество елементов в масиве может быть разное

Comment: @РоманФедоров значит надо запрос делать так, чтоб производителя вперед ставить

Comment: сделайте  ключ на каждый элемент и делайте сортировку

Answer (score 0):

В списке функций для работы с массивами не нашел ничего похожего на "извлечь элемент массива, соответствующий условию". Полагаю, что "производитель" всегда соответствует `attribute_id = 19` (иначе придется сравнивать с `name = Производитель`). Ну и делаем как-то так:

```
$a = [
['attribute_id' => 1, 'name' => 'фигня1', 'text' => 'фигня1'],
['attribute_id' => 2, 'name' => 'фигня2', 'text' => 'фигня2'],
['attribute_id' => 3, 'name' => 'фигня3', 'text' => 'фигня3'],
['attribute_id' => 4, 'name' => 'фигня4', 'text' => 'фигня4'],
['attribute_id' => 5, 'name' => 'фигня5', 'text' => 'фигня5'],
['attribute_id' => 19, 'name' => 'Производитель', 'text' => 'Saeco']
];

$temp = array_filter($a,function($i){return $i['attribute_id'] == 19;});
unset($a[key($temp)]);
array_unshift($a, current($temp));
```

Ну и другой вариант, если в этих ваших опен-картах можно как-то вфигачиваться в запрос, то можно просто добавить в условие `ORDER BY` такую несложную штуку как `attribute_id = 19 DESC` - тогда производитель всегда будет на первом месте, а остальные элементы - ну как получится.